# UWP Loading indicator does not appear

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP application and I want to show a content dialog while loading data.

This is my loading dialog which is called via the LoadedCommand.

```
    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
            await dialogService.ShowLoadingDialogAsync();

            await LoadPaymentsAsync(new PaymentListFilterChangedMessage { TimeRangeStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(DEFAULT_MONTH_BACK) });
            //Refresh balance control with the current account
            await BalanceViewModel.UpdateBalanceCommand.ExecuteAsync();

            await dialogService.HideLoadingDialogAsync();
    }
```

I also tried to to call it via the DispatcherHelper:

```
    private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            await dialogService.ShowLoadingDialogAsync();

            await LoadPaymentsAsync(new PaymentListFilterChangedMessage { TimeRangeStart = DateTime.Now.AddYears(DEFAULT_MONTH_BACK) });
            //Refresh balance control with the current account
            await BalanceViewModel.UpdateBalanceCommand.ExecuteAsync();

            await dialogService.HideLoadingDialogAsync();
        });
    }
```

But that didn't change anything. The method in the DialogService looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a loading Dialog.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task ShowLoadingDialogAsync(string? message = null)
    {
        // Be sure no other dialog is open.
        await HideLoadingDialogAsync();

        loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog { Text = message ?? Strings.LoadingLabel };

        CoreApplicationView coreWindow = CoreApplication.MainView;

        // Dispatcher needed to run on UI Thread
        CoreDispatcher dispatcher = coreWindow.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

        // RunAsync all of the UI info.
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            async () =>
            {
                await loadingDialog.ShowAsync();
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hides the previously opened Loading Dialog.
    /// </summary>
    public Task HideLoadingDialogAsync()
    {
        loadingDialog?.Hide();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Funny enough on other occasions, for example when I load data from a webservice instead of the database this does work without any issues.

Comment: Does the following solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UWP Loading indicator does not appear

During the testing, The `LoadingDialog`  Text  property cause the problem, if you want make Text property could effect for xaml content, please make it as dependency property like the following.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="main_content"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class LoadingDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public LoadingDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(LoadingDialog), new PropertyMetadata(0));




    private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

And now you could use  `DialogService` to show the dialog proper.

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await dialogService.ShowLoadingDialogAsync();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    await dialogService.HideLoadingDialogAsync();
}
```

Update

The other guess is the loading process is very quick that cause dialog disappears before it can be displayed. So you try to add task delay manually after
`await BalanceViewModel.UpdateBalanceCommand.ExecuteAsync();` line

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. That seems to work when I have it via the Task.Delay, but not with the actual loading of data from EF Core / my SQLite DB. So it seems something is blocking there.

Comment: So, the problem may not occur in the contentdialog. could you check if ef core work well?

Comment: Have you tried to hidden dialog within ui thread?

Comment: you mean to call hide await dispatcher.RunAsync?

Comment: Yep, please try it and let me know the result

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately. Although I'm not sure how calling the hiding there could help with the the dialog not appearing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227880/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-npadrutt).